# Visual Website Optimizer A/B Testing On Local Machine

Tags: web-deployment, ab-testing, abtest, vwo

So I have my app running on my local server, I am trying to a/b test the feature with [Visual Website Optimizer](https://vwo.com).

I put the server address(publicly not available) in the preview URL, but when I open the preview page, it gives a warning saying "Error: Cookie could not be set.". Cookies are enabled.

My question is, should the preview page (or default campaign url) be publicly reachable for VWO to work properly?

Answer (score 3):

In order to run the VWO on localhost, you just need to make a small adjustment to the **/etc/hosts** file. Just add "**localhost.com**" at the end of the line that says "1**27.0.0.1 localhost**"

[image]

Now you can run the VWO on any URL that starts with http://localhost.com.

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the page should be publicly reachable only for Screenshots of the variations. Live previews should work even if the URL is accessible only locally. Though you should use a valid URL i.e. a URL having a valid domain name and TLD.

For any other info / debugging I would request you to send a mail to support (at) wingify (dot) com if not already done so that an exact solution can be shared.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are opening your website as an html file in your file system. You can host your static website locally with [HarpJS](http://harpjs.com/). Install it through npm

```
npm install -g harp
```

Go to the root dir of your site and run `harp server`. Now you'll be able to open your site on http://localhost:9000

Also I have written an article how to easier develop experiments for Optimizely/VWO usage http://bit.ly/1C4vtSA

Comment: I have an angular app, where VWO doesn't work when serving the app via grunt (live url is http://localhost:9005 after running 'grunt serve'). I asked VWO and they said their code does not work with localhost with port #'s but maybe localhost without it only?           "VWO Rep: I have checked it with my devs + would need to inform you that your localhost has port number in it, so our tool do not works with that due to some internal technical reasons. It should work with the other localhosts that don't have port numbers." Did u find a way for it to work with localhost:9000 url like u mentioned?